# best excel formula for counting the number of cells in a range with two or more criteria (one of which crietria has multiple values)

Tags: excel, matrix, formula

I would like to count the number of cells in the range A1:B4 which have the following criteria.

criteria 1) Name = Josh and.... 
criteria 2 (with multiple values, OR) Status = 1 or 2

I have been able to use dcounta effectively (though only with one criteria for each column: name and status) such as in the following example:

My dataset is:

```
name    status
josh    1
josh    2
josh    3
```

**Example 1: Single criteria per column using DCOUNTA**

```
formula = =DCOUNTA(A2:B5,"status",A6:B7)
result = 1

name    status
josh    1
```

But whenever I use a second criteria (adding another row to the status column) the DCOUNTA doesn't work.

```
name    status
josh    1
        2
```

**Question:** Is it possible to count the number of times, name = josh, and status = 1 or 2 can be found using another method, where the data would be represented in a matrix format (name down the side, status across the top).

```
Name | Status 1 | Status 2 | Status 3
Josh      1            1        1
Amanda    0            0        0
```

Comment: Do you mean column status1 our status2 is equal to 1? Di you want to count number of rows, or if both columns are 1 then your formula should return 2?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Array Formula (hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER):**

```
=IF(A$2:A$9="Josh";1)*SUM(IF(B2:B9>0;1);IF(C2:C9>0;1);IF(D2:D9>0;1))
```

Where the data looks like this

```
Name    Status1 Status2 Status3
Josh    1       1       1
Amanda  0       0       0
Josh    1       2       0
```

**Result: 5**

If you need more contraints just add them to the first if.